# I can not properly transfer intent through notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have 3 types of notifications. depending on the types I open different screens. for this I pass parameters to the intent. Then he took of intent. The problem is that all the notifications contain the last sent intent. it is because I use the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` I have tried other flags, but they also do not work. I need to notice each contain its intent and by pressing it into the main Activity transmitted data I needed.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static int ID_NITIF =1;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("content");
        int groupid = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("group_id"));
        generateNotification(context,title, message,groupid,intent);
    }
..............
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message,int groupid,Intent data) {

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        if (groupid==1){
            intent.putExtra("guest",data.getStringExtra("guest"));
            intent.putExtra("hotel",data.getStringExtra("hotel"));
            intent.putExtra("room",data.getStringExtra("room"));
        }
        if (groupid==5){
            intent.putExtra("hotel",data.getStringExtra("hotel"));
        }
        if (groupid==4){
            intent.putExtra("hotel",data.getStringExtra("hotel"));
            intent.putExtra("guest",data.getStringExtra("guest"));
        }

        intent.putExtra("group_id",groupid);
        Log.d("mylogout","group_id: "+groupid);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification   = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm))
                .setTicker("Новое сообщение")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(ID_NITIF++, notification);
    }
}
```

and in MyActivity

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Bundle arguments;
        Fragment fragment;
        String guest;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            if(extras.containsKey("group_id"))
            {
                int msg = extras.getInt("group_id");
                String hotel = extras.getString("hotel");
                switch (msg){
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new PagerLogbookContainer();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, hotel);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                        setTitle(hotel);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        guest = extras.getString("guest");
                        String room = extras.getString("room");
                        fragment = new Guest();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
                        arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
                        arguments.putString("room",room);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "guest").commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        guest = extras.getString("guest");
                        fragment = new Survey();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
                        arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
```

in onCreate()

```
 onNewIntent(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. for a week, no one could help. to the data stored in each notification you want to add action in intent `intent.setAction("some");`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it may be help full you**

```
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Bundle arguments;
    Fragment fragment;
    String guest;
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("group_id"))
        {
            int msg = extras.getInt("group_id");
            String hotel = extras.getString("hotel");
            displayView(int msg)
        }
    public void displayView(int msg) {

    switch (msg) {
    case 5:
         fragment = new PagerLogbookContainer();
          arguments = new Bundle();
          arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, hotel);
        break;
    case 1:
          guest = extras.getString("guest");
          String room = extras.getString("room");
          fragment = new Guest();
            arguments = new Bundle();
             arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
            arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
            arguments.putString("room",room);
        break;
    case 4:
         guest = extras.getString("guest");
         fragment = new Survey();
         arguments = new Bundle();
         arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
         arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but not the question. everything is working fine. the problem is that each new notification overwrites past. if I send the first notification that the population and the second guest on the guest had left it when you click on any one of them will open the fragment "guest left." this is why a second notification has blocked what was in the former. Activity itself takes the wrong data from the notification